# Query analyzer or profiler for SQL Server CE 4

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4, query-analyzer

Is there any query analyzer or profiler for Microsoft SQL Server CE 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 + SQL Server Compact 4 Tools, you get a query analyzer (if you use VS Premium or higher). You can also use my VS add-in: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

There is no profiler, only Query Analyzer (SHOWPLAN)